# How to use matplotlib to plot a function graph if I have 2 prepared np.arrays of points?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I provide a python-code which solves Gauss equations and plots a function graph. I have a problem in plotting my function. When I try to plot a function graph for example - "2sin(2πx)" I see lines which connect point and it isn't that i would see.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from matplotlib import mlab

print 'case1=2sin(2πx)'
print 'case2=cos(2πx)'
print 'case3=5x^3 + x^2 + 5'

Your_function=raw_input("Enter your choise of your function:   ")


def Choising_of_function(x, Your_function):
    if Your_function=='case1':
        return 2*math.sin(2*x*math.pi)
    elif Your_function=='case2':
        return math.cos(2*x*math.pi)
    elif Your_function=='case3':
        return 5*x**3 + x**2 + 5

Dimension_of_pol=int(raw_input("Enter your degree of polynom:   "))
Points=int(raw_input("Enter number of points:   "))# I just need only limited numbers of points to plot a function graph
Interval=int(raw_input("Enter interval of your points:   "))
dx=float(raw_input("Enter interval your dx:   "))


X_val=[]
Y_val=[]

for i in range(Points):# First, i generate my values of x
    x = random.uniform(-Interval, Interval)
    X_val.append(x)

for x in X_val:
    y=Choising_of_function(x, Your_function)
    Y_val.append(y)
print X_val, Y_val

Arr_Xo=[[x**i for i in range(Dimension_of_pol)] for x in X_val]
print Arr_Xo

D_mod={}
D={}
for y, x in zip(Y_val, X_val):
    D_mod[y]=x

Arr_X_o=np.array(Arr_Xo)
print Arr_X_o      
Arr_X=np.array(X_val) #My array of x-values
print Arr_X
Arr_Y=np.array(Y_val) #My array of y-values
print Arr_Y

m = np.linalg.lstsq(Arr_X_o, Arr_Y)[0]
print m
pylab.plot(Arr_X, Arr_Y, 'go')
line=plt.plot(Arr_X, Arr_Y)
line.show()
```

How i can plot my function without using frange.

My array of x:

```
[-15.9836388   13.78848867  -3.39805316  12.04429943 -12.34344464
 -19.66512508   6.8480724   -5.58674018   7.59985149  11.46357551
  -4.96507337  -2.40178658  -1.71320151 -12.87164233  -3.26385184
  -7.44683254   5.52525074  -9.16879057   3.70939966  -4.80486815
 -10.35409227   6.72283255   2.00436008   8.68484529 -17.81750773]
```

My array of y:

```
[ 0.20523902 -1.941802   -1.19527441  0.54952271 -1.66506802  1.72228361
 -1.63215286  1.03684409 -1.17406016  0.45373838  0.43538662 -1.15733373
  1.94677887  1.44373207 -1.99242991 -0.65576448 -0.31598064 -1.74524107
 -1.9352764   1.88232214 -1.58727561 -1.97093284  0.05478352 -1.83473627
  1.8227666 ]
```

I paste all of it in :

```
line=plt.plot(Arr_X, Arr_Y)
plt.show()
```

And my function graph doesnt looks like 2*sin(2px)

[image]

Comment: please try to formulate your problem more clearly. what meas `` i see lines which connect point and it isn't that i would see.''??? What is your input data? Your imports are redundant: pylab already contains numpy and pyplot! Also, line.show() should not worlk. You should use plt.show().

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your x axis values are not in order, therefore when you plot them your points will not be joined to the next point on the x axis, giving a graph that looks like the one in the question. A test of this will be to use `plt.scatter` instead of `plt.plot`:

[image]

This shows that the points you are generating are in the correct shape as seen in the left most image, however you are just generating the x values slightly wrong.

In order to get a nice looking graph you need to change the way you generate the x values. This can be done using `np.linspace`, the documentation can be found [here](http://numpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

```
# for i in range(Points):  # First, i generate my values of x
#     x = random.uniform(-Interval, Interval)
#     X_val.append(x)

# replace the above 3 lines with the one below
X_val = np.linspace(-Interval,Interval,Points)
```

In addition, there is no need to assign `plt.plot` to a variable, therefore the last 3 lines of your code should be replaced with:

```
# pylab.plot(Arr_X, Arr_Y, 'go')
# line=plt.plot(Arr_X, Arr_Y)
# line.show()

# replace the above 3 lines with the one below
pylab.plot(Arr_X, Arr_Y)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I do not know what the reason is to

```
pylab.plot(Arr_X, Arr_Y, 'go')
```

as well as

```
line=plt.plot(Arr_X, Arr_Y)
```

Why do you need pylab to plot instead of just using pyplot?

Your
line.show() in line 63 gives me an attribute error
"list" object has no attribute "show"

only **plt** has show(), if you see in **print dir(plt)**

As I am to lazy to go trough your full code stick to this general plotting example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure, axis = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.6, 6.1))

for x in range(0, 500):
    axis.plot(x, x*2, 'o-')

plt.show()
```

Comment: you should spell it `axes` or `ax` not `axis`.  One naming choice mpl has internally is `Axes` whole thing and  `Axis` is the spines + ticks.  Your choice of names can make it more confusing than it already is.

Comment: @tacaswell I think its my decision how to name parameters....I could have also named it **monkey, banana = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.6, 6.1))** (like I normally do..)

Comment: You are correct you _can_ name them anything you want, but the question is _should_ you.  This naming is needlessing confusing as `axis` is not an instance of an `Axis` object.   Also, creating 500 single-point `Line2D` objects via repeated calls to `ax.plot` in not good practice either.